# time decay factor for posts / updates in newsfeed using neo4j

Tags: php, sql, neo4j

i am using neo4j to retrieve news feed using this query.

```
MATCH (u:Users {user_id:140}),(p:Posts)-[:CREATED_BY]->(pu:Users)
WHERE  (p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u) OR  (p:PUBLIC AND (u)-[:FOLLOW]->(pu)) OR 
 (p:PRIVATE AND (p)-[:SHARED_WITH]->(u))
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:POST_MEDIA]->(f)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:COMMENT]->(c)<-[:COMMENT]-(u3) RETURN 
(p.meta_score+0.2*p.likes+0.1*p.dislikes + 10/(((".time()."- 
p.created_time)/3600)+0.1)) as score,
 {user_id:pu.user_id,firstname:pu.firstname,lastname:pu.lastname,
profile_photo:pu.profile_photo,username:pu.username} as pu,  p,  
    collect({user_id:u3.user_id,profile_photo:u3.profile_photo,text:c.text}) as comment,
 collect(f) as file ORDER BY score  DESC,
p.post_id DESC LIMIT 25
```

In this equation for getting score right now i am using  mainly this equation `p.meta_score+0.1*p.likes-0.05*p.dislikes + 10/(((current_time- 
    p.created_time)/3600)+0.1)) as score`   here i hace added 0.1 to prevent infinity error as current_time may be nearly equal to post created_time( `as p refer post class`)
    Here its nice for single day but after a day the `time` part doesn't contribute well total  score as the way i am calculating time decay factor is not consistent i need a equation which plays its role consistently (I means decrease score at lesser rate) for first seven days and than start decreasing its contribution towards score at an higher rate. one way was using `trigonometry's tan or cot` functions but the problem is that after some intervals they changes there signs.I shall be thankfull to everybody gives me further suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

At a basic level,  it is common to use an exponential time decay function here. Something like:

```
score = score / elapsedTime^2
```

As elapsed time since the post increases, the value of the score decreases exponentially. Sites like Reddit and Hacker News use much [more complicated algorithms](https://github.com/clux/decay), but that is the basic idea.

Comment: does neo4j cypher supports exponent

Comment: Thanks for link @WilliamLyon